# sshd on Fedora: Recent changes to UsePAM break existing security; PermitRootPassword & UsePAM no not honored, minimal PAM config doesn't work either

Tags: ssh, fedora, pam, root

I did upgrade on a Fedora Server and was SHOCKED to discover **thousands of root attacks on my publicly facing servers and I can't seem to figure out how to stop them!**

To be clear; It IS possible to log in to the root account with a password when it should not be possible and the "root attacks" are crackers trying to do just that.

Involved, or possibly involved, Packages are:

Fedora Server 32
openssh-server-8.3p1-3.fc32.x86_64
pam-1.3.1-26.fc32.x86_64
fprintd-pam-1.90.1-1.fc32.x86_64
pam_afs_session-2.6-12.fc32.x86_64
gnome-keyring-pam-3.36.0-1.fc32.x86_64
systemd-pam-245.8-2.fc32.x86_64
pam_passwdqc-1.4.0-1.fc32.x86_64

... I'm not really sure what the older stuff was, but not older than FC27, that's for sure, and probably a lot younger.

I had been relying upon:

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

Before that, it was `without-password`, and both seemed to still work until this change.

Note that the following comment in the default `sshd_config` file seemed to me to be spurious as the `PermitRootLogin` parameter was honored, but APPARENTLY it was intended as a warning about `UsePAM` changing in the future and we should prepare. Well, now - *and I'm guessing here!* - it has become the actual forced-upon-us setting:

```
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
```

**PLEASE NOTE the bit about `UsePam no` not being supported on Fedora!**

The result of this change, as stated above, was that now I have root attacks. I am NOT using PAM, and DO NOT WANT to use PAM, so, to use an old-fashioned expression, "this burns my bottom."

However, I TRIED setting the "PAM configuration" I don't even want but it didn't work. I tried this:

```
UsePAM yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

This is exactly what the comment appears to ask us to do, but it doesn't work.

By the way, I DO REQUIRE password authentication for some accounts.

So, I tried an explicit `UsePAM no`, even though I haven't a clue what "several problems" this "may cause." (Any comments about what those problems are would be very welcome.) **However, `UsePAM no` doesn't work, either!**

On the one hand, I can't turn off ssh as this functionality is required, and, by the way, root access is required, too, for some remote backup functionality that spans many accounts, but I also cannot allow a root crack! This is a DISASTER!

Does anyone have a minimalistic PAM setup that can let someone like me keep going without undue delay? ...Or, if I have to go through a full PAM setup, can someone point me to a good tutorial or some such? I really don't have time to learn about a system I don't want!

It might be worth mentioning that other than discussed in this question, there are NO modifications to the `sshd` configuration from stock OTHER THAN the `PermitRootLogin` attribute and the three PAM related lines above this that were tried temporarily.

**NEW DATA**

I discovered that of the many servers I updated last Friday, ONLY ONE of them appears to have this problem! All the rest are on the SAME O/S version.

One key difference I discovered is that on the one that's got the problem, there's NOTHING going into `/var/log/secure` since the update!

**NEW DATA II**

It turned out the log file problem was related to `SELinux`. Once fixed, `/var/log/secure` was being written to again, but it didn't fix the problem of still being able to log in to root via password when it should not be allowed.

Hmmm...

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say "thousands of root attacks"? What is the actual problem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hi Michael. I mean attempts at login from "unauthorized persons." ...On a functioning SSHD, attempted logins to root via password when either without-password or prohibit-password, upon successful login those are NOT shown to the user as log-fails. At least, not on my distribution / versions. I take such attempted logins as attacks since they're clearly not authorized users!

Comment: Ah, yes, now invalid logins are accounted and displayed at the next successful login. These attacks were always happening, now you are just more aware of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oops! Wrong: It is still possible to log in via password. Hence, NOT WORKING.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the root user can ssh in with a password?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, exactly. ... I can make that more clear above in a minute...

Comment: It reads like your PAM configuration could be relevant. Exactly what update changed this behavior? It may help to reference package versions.

Comment: @AaronCopley "Exactly what update" was a "dnf update" - IOW, updating the whole box. It did NOT update the kernel. As for PAM, I have not - and would not / will not - created a "pam configuration" unless forced (which looks like what is happening right now. So, whatever PAM config there is is "stock Fedora Server 32." ...I'll put the PAM package versions in the question body in mere moments, thanks.